# Get the selected option's text field in controller in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know how to get the value of the selected option in the dropdown in controller. Using

```
params[:category_id]
```

My question is for a select like this

```
<select name="category_id">
  <option value="0">New</option>
  <option value="1">SubCategory1</option>
  <option value="2">SubCategory2</option>
  <option value="3">SubCategory3</option>
</select>
```

How can i also get the selected text after request is posted to controller? So if user selects Option 1, I want "0" as well as "New".

Comment: you can get the selected value in the params, if you want selected text, then send it as an additional parameter

Comment: @arivarasan. Thanks for the reply. I am quite new to ruby. What is the best way to create a new parameter? This is how my view looks like `<%=  select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select($config["Categories"]), :class=> "form-control") %>` where config["Categories"] returns a map

Answer (score 0):

@shaurya, Not sure why you want the text value from the form post. Can you look up the value in config['Categories'] using category_id?